package contacts_service problem when I run the program with this package
I am trying to use the contacts_service package: ^0.6.3
I just put this in the pubspec.yaml I did a pub get so far everything is going well but when I compile I get this error every time.
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':contacts_service'.

> Could not create an instance of type com.android.build.api.variant.impl.LibraryVariantBuilderImpl.
> Namespace not specified. Specify a namespace in the module's build file. See https://d.android.com/r/tools/upgrade-assistant/set-namespace for information about setting the namespace.

     If you've specified the package attribute in the source AndroidManifest.xml, you can use the AGP Upgrade Assistant to migrate to the namespace value in the build file. Refer to https://d.android.com/r/tools/upgrade-assistant/agp-upgrade-assistant for general information about using the AGP Upgrade Assistant.

The source:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:contacts_service/contacts_service.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: ContactListPage(),
    );
  }
}

class ContactListPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ContactListPageState createState() => _ContactListPageState();
}

class _ContactListPageState extends State<ContactListPage> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Flutter Contact List'),
      ),

    );
  }
}`


could you please give me a sample build.gradle and androidmanifest.xml for he run correctly ? thank you
